# why function argument is available for class inside function even without passing them to class ? python

Tags: python, function, class, arguments

I denfind a class inside a function, I found the function argument is available for class even I doesn't initialize the class with function arguments.

my code like

```
def func1(p1,p2):
    class test1(object):
        def __init__(self, arg1):
            self.v1 = p1
            self.v2 = p2
            self.v3 = arg1
    return test1 
testclass = func1(2,13)
testobj = testclass(234)
print(testobj.v1)
print(testobj.v2)
print(testobj.v3)
```

Print is fine , can someone explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function parameters are converted to local variables when the function is called. When you define `test1.__init__`, `arg1` is a local variable initialized from the parameter list. `p1` and `p2` are free variables - they are expected to be resolved in the outer scope at runtime. `test1` is compiled as an inner class to `func1` which defines these as local variables. So, these variables are resolved to local variables in `func1`. But these local variables only exist when `func1` is called, so how could you possibly use `test1` outside of the function?

Python recognizes this odd situation and creates a *closure* whenever `func1` is called. `test1.__init__` knows that `p1` and `p2` are to be referenced in the closure. And `func1` knows to put the `p1` and `p2` values in the closure then create a new version of the `test1` class whenever it is called.

As a result, each time you call `func1`, you get a new special case of class `test1` which has been parameterized with the `p1` and `p2` values you used to call `func1`. This association is setup when `func1` returns and lasts for the lifetime of the class object returned by `func1`. Each call to `func1` gives you a different class.

```
testclass = func1(2,13)    # create class <locals>.test1
                           #     and the closure (2, 13)
testobj = testclass(234)   # instantiate the class which assigns
                           #    self.v1 <-- 234 from the parameter list
                           #    self.v2 <-- 2 from the closure
                           #    self.v3 <-- 13 from the closure
```